# Nutch updatedb killed and skipped batch ids

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch 2.0 and solr 4.0 and am having minimal success I have 3 urls and my regex-urlfilter.xml is set to allow everything.
I ran this script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Nutch crawl

export NUTCH_HOME=~/java/workspace/Nutch2.0/runtime/local

# depth in the web exploration
n=1
# number of selected urls for fetching
maxUrls=50000
# solr server
solrUrl=http://localhost:8983

for (( i = 1 ; i <= $n ; i++ ))
do

log=$NUTCH_HOME/logs/log                                                                                                                                                           

# Generate
$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch generate -topN $maxUrls > $log

batchId=`sed -n 's|.*batch id: \(.*\)|\1|p' < $log`

# rename log file by appending the batch id
log2=$log$batchId
mv $log $log2
log=$log2

# Fetch
$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch fetch $batchId >> $log

# Parse
$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch parse $batchId >> $log

# Update
$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch updatedb >> $log

# Index
$NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch solrindex $solrUrl $batchId >> $log

done
----------------------------
```

Of course I bin/nutch inject urls before i run the script, but when I look at the logs, I see Skipping : different batch id and some of the urls that I see are ones that arent in the seed.txt and I want to include them
into solr, but they aren't added.
I have 3 urls in my seed.txt

After I ran this script I had tried
`bin/nutch parse -force -all`
`bin/nutch updatedb`
`bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/sites -reindex`

My questions are as follows.
1. The last three commands why were they necessary?
2. How do I get all of the urls during the parse job, even with the -force -all i still get different batch id skipping
3. The script above, if i set generate -topN to 5. Does this mean if a site has a link to another site to another site to another site to another site to another site. That it will be included in the fetch/parse cycle?
4. What about this command, why is this even mentioned :
`bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/sites -depth 3 -topN 10000 -threads 3.`
5. When i run bin/nutch updateb it takes 1-2 mineuts then it echos Killed. This concerns me. Please Help.

And yes, I have read a lot of pages on nutch and solr and I have been trying to figure this out for weeks now.

Answer (score 2):

> some of the URLs that I see are ones that aren't in the `seed.txt`

I think that this is happening due to URL normalization. *Nutch* does this URL normalization due to which the original URL is changed or converted to a more standard format.

**for #1:** You injected and then executed generate-fetch phases...right? Those 3 phases in your question are required for parsing of crawled data, updating the db with newly discovered pages and to index them respectively.

**for #2:** Sorry but I didn't get your question.

**for #3:** No. `topN` set to 5 means *nutch* will select top 5 URLs from the `while` bunch of URLs eligible for fetching. It will consider only these selected high scored URLs for fetching.

**for #4:** That is a single command which invokes all *nutch* phases automatically. So you won't have to manually execute separate command for each phase. Just have single command and it will do all stuff.

**for #5:** There will be some exception logged in the hadoop logs. Provide the stack trace and error message so that I comment on it. Without that I can't think of anything.

Comment: this might help on question 5, I am running this on a server with only 618 MB RAM

Comment: well there are high chances that you might be facing OOM.

Comment: @peter Parsing the crawled data is required. It can be done either by running a separate parse command or setting a config which enables parsing to be done in the fetch phase itself.

Comment: @TejasP How can i run a separate parse command? I am using the above script to crawl a 2 sites. The default file says "Since 2.0 this is set to false as a safer default" , so will setting it to true will not cause issue? The parsing command seems to skip a lot of urls and it increases the time for each cycle of generate/fetch/parse/update. The fetch time is around 10 to 15 mins and the rest 20 mins are for generate, parse and update. How can i make the fetching continuous and fetch more number of urls in a smaller time frame (running another script or changing some setting in nutch 2.1) ?

Comment: @peter : set "fetcher.parse" to true so that parsing happens along with fetching. This should be a time saver for overall nutch crawl cycle.